# Flatten a Nested Dictionary collected from Tick Data for 2 different 'instrument_token'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, flatten

I have received tick data as below:
It has nested dict as 'olhc' and 'depth'. *Again the 'depth' is nested as 'buy' and 'sell'*. Here I am facing more problem.

```
[
{'tradable': True, 'mode': 'full', 'instrument_token': 20471298,         
'last_price': 65.0, 'last_quantity': 1500, 'average_price': 66.0, 'volume': 
3000, 'buy_quantity': 51000, 'sell_quantity': 54000, 'ohlc': {'open': 67.0, 
'high': 67.0, 'low': 65.0, 'close': 58.8}, 'change': 10.544217687074834, 
'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 22, 10, 46, 28), 'oi': 52500, 
'oi_day_high': 55500, 'oi_day_low': 52500, 'timestamp': 
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 22, 15, 39, 6), 'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 
0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 60.0, 'orders': 
1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 21.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 
'price': 20.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 5.4, 'orders': 1}], 
'sell': [{'quantity': 0, 'price': 0.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 3000, 
'price': 97.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 121.0, 'orders': 
1}, {'quantity': 48000, 'price': 144.3, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 0, 
'price': 0.0, 'orders': 0}]}}, 

{'tradable': True, 'mode': 'full', 'instrument_token': 11955714, 
'last_price': 70.5, 'last_quantity': 1500, 'average_price': 69.36, 'volume': 
24000, 'buy_quantity': 45000, 'sell_quantity': 64500, 'ohlc': {'open': 55.0, 
'high': 74.45, 'low': 54.0, 'close': 51.8}, 'change': 36.1003861003861, 
'last_trade_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 22, 15, 20, 35), 'oi': 
166500, 'oi_day_high': 187500, 'oi_day_low': 166500, 'timestamp': 
datetime.datetime(2018, 10, 22, 15, 34, 36), 'depth': {'buy': [{'quantity': 
1500, 'price': 71.35, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 69.3, 
'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 69.1, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 
1500, 'price': 68.05, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 68.0, 
'orders': 1}], 'sell': [{'quantity': 1500, 'price': 78.0, 'orders': 1}, 
{'quantity': 1500, 'price': 79.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 
80.0, 'orders': 1}, {'quantity': 1500, 'price': 90.0, 'orders': 1}, 
{'quantity': 58500, 'price': 105.6, 'orders': 1}]}}, 
]
```

I want to flatten the entire data and save into pandas dataframe with all fields in separate column.

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.io.json.json_normalize`?

Comment: No Sir, I am very new to python. Can you please explain a bit more..

Comment: See [`pandas.io.json.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

Comment: Yea as advised I have checked the same but it was unable to Flatten the depth.buy and depth.sell. both the columns are flatten to 1st level only like: '[{'quantity': 1500, 'price': 76.1, 'orders': 1...' I need to flatten these two columns also to indivisibly columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pandas.io.json.normalize.json_normalize` in Pandas as at **v0.23.4** doesn't support normalizing record paths that share the same *root*.

Normalizing this kind of object needs to be done separately on the same data. The resulting data frame objects can be concatenated using `pandas.core.reshape.concat.concat`.

First normalize one of the nested buy or sell lists,

```
buys_keypath = ['depth', 'buy']

df_from_buys_keypath = json_normalize(dct, 
                                      [['depth', 'buy']],
                                      record_prefix='depth.buy.')
```

Then normalize the rest of the data with the other nested list as the record path.

```
def keypaths(dct):
    ret_list = []
    for k in dct.keys():
        if isinstance(dct[k], dict):
            for keypath in keypaths(dct[k]):
                keypaths_ = keypath if isinstance(keypath, list) else [keypath]
                ret_list += [[k, *keypaths_]]
        else:
            ret_list += [k,]
    return ret_list

rest_keypath = list(
    filter(
        lambda keypath: keypath != ['depth', 'buy'], # filter out buys_keypath
        keypaths(dct[0])
    )
)

df_from_rest_keypath = json_normalize(dct,
                                      [['depth', 'sell']],
                                      rest_keypath,
                                      record_prefix='depth.sell.')
```

Finally, concatenate both data frame objects along their column

```
df = pandas.concat([df_from_buys_keypath, df_from_other_keypath],
                   axis=1)
```